# Cloud Run Trigger execution failed when creating a service

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am having problems creating a service in cloud run. I am following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/deploy-continuously?hl=es-419), using the Go template that GCP provides.
But I get this error: `Trigger execution failed: source code could not be built or deployed, no logs are found`.
I tried with the template that they provide, and with my own application in Go. The app works fine when running with docker.
What could be happening? I don't have more logs than that.

[image: error creating service]

Edit: In log explorer more logs are shown and there was an error which showed the IAM API disabled. Enabling this api, the creation of the service works fine

Comment: Can you share your error logs? Are you using Cloud build to deploy to cloud run. If so, share your cloudbuild.yaml. also make sure you have given enough  permission. if not, provide minimal reproducible steps.

Comment: Do you have Cloud Build API activated?

Comment: I didn't have Cloud Build API activated, that wasn't obvious to me (or the error message) so I had no clue what was happening until I found your comment @guillaumeblaquiere — thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might sound redundant but have you checked the logs on Log Explorer / Stackdriver? The tutorial you just shared should be pretty straightforward. Maybe there (Log Explorer) we can have some more information

Comment: Thanks, there was a log that I had not seen in the cloud run logs, but it does appear in Log Explorer. The IAM API was not enabled